# What happens if you save your buddies instead of the civilians?

Tags: far-cry-2

At about the midpoint in the game the player has to choose between saving a group of civilians at a church or saving one (or possibly more) buddies at the bar.

At first I thought of saving the buddies because we had a personal relationship, but then I was unsure because it couldn't be moral to let the greater number of civilians die.  Then I realized I hated my main buddy so I saved the civilians and all of the buddies died.

What happens if you save the buddies at Mike's Bar instead of the civilians at the church?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Same thing.  There's a shootout at the bar and everyone gets killed but you.**

Notably, no mention of civilian deaths is ever heard if you decide to leave the church to its fate.

End-of-game spoiler:

> Your teammates aren't as killed as you think they are.

Comment: Really, they deserved it though.  Why anyone would take cover in the bar rather than the heavily-fortified-and-filled-with-guns armory across the street is beyond me.